# Rails 4: display clickable link in mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, actionmailer

In my Rails app, I have an Invite model:

```
class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'

  before_create :generate_token

  def generate_token
    self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([self.calendar_id, self.recipient_role, Time.now, rand].join)
  end

end
```

With the following migration:

```
class CreateInvites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invites do |t|
      t.string :email 
      t.integer :calendar_id
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.string :recipient_role
      t.string :token
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I use the Invite model to create invitations, through the following `InvitesController`:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params) # Make a new Invite
    @invite.sender_id = current_user.id # set the sender to the current user
    @calendar = Calendar.find_by_id(@invite.calendar_id)
    authorize @calendar
    if @invite.save
      InviteMailer.invite(@invite).deliver #send the invite data to our mailer to deliver the email
    else
      format.html { render :edit, notice: 'Invitation could not be sent.' }
    end
    redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar)
  end

  private

  def invite_params
    params.require(:invite).permit(:email, :calendar_id)
  end

end
```

Here is the `InviteMailer`:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def invite(invite)
    @link = new_user_registration_path invite_token: invite.token
    mail to: invite.email, subject: "Calendy Invitation"
  end

end
```

And here is the corresponding mailer view:

```
You've been invited to join a calendar.
Click here to view this calendar: <%= @link %>
```

When I create an invite and I check the logs on my server, I can see that the following email has been generated by the mailer:

```
InviteMailer#invite: processed outbound mail in 13.7ms

Sent mail to example@gmail.com (57.6ms)
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 10:50:13 -0700
From: from@example.com
To: example@gmail.com
Message-ID: <55f85a5515500_1cf93ff0b4ef71144524c@XXX.local.mail>
Subject: Calendy Invitation
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <body>
    You've been invited to join a calendar.
Click here to view this calendar: /account/sign_up?invite_token=cf7fb2ab8ad0774a99c1cdf7baf0bd44796c2f0f
  </body>
</html>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/calendars/3
```

I had two problems here:

1. I don't understand why I have `/account/sign_up?invite_token=cf7fb2ab8ad0774a99c1cdf7baf0bd44796c2f0f` in the email and not `http://localhost:3000/calendars/3/account/sign_up?invite_token=cf7fb2ab8ad0774a99c1cdf7baf0bd44796c2f0f`
2. I am not sure that the above link, generated by `<%= @link %>`, is clickable. And when I try to make it clickable, with `<%= link_to @link %>`, [as recommended here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view), I get the following error:

   ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Invites#create
   No route matches {:action=>"index"}

   You've been invited to join a calendar.
   Click here to view this calendar: <%= link_to @link %>

With the error coming from the line `Click here to view this calendar: <%= link_to @link %>`

I would highly appreciate any insight regarding the above items.

Any idea?

Comment: `@link = new_user_registration_url invite_token: invite.token` instead of `@link = new_user_registration_path invite_token: invite.token`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `new_user_registration_url` instead of `new_user_registration_path`

`_path` helpers provide a site-root-relative path. You should probably use this most of the time.

`_url` helpers provide an absolute path, including protocol and server name. I've found that I mainly use these in emails when creating links to the app on the server. They should mainly be used when providing links for external use. (Think email links, RSS, and things like the copy and paste URL field under a YouTube video's "Share" section.)

And use `link_to` in mailer class is a bad  thing

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def invite(invite)
    @invite = invite
    mail to: invite.email, subject: "Calendy Invitation"
  end

end
```

**Mailer view:**

```
Click here to view this calendar: <%= link_to "link", new_user_registration_url(invite_token: @invite.token) %>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help and this explanation about _path VS. _url. Just a question: once I update the content of @link, then what should I use in the mailer: `<%= @link %>` or `<%= link_to @link %>` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer.